# can't copy string into linked list by using strcpy()

Tags: copy, strcpy

have problem copying the string in array into the linked list

```
typedef struct{
    char census_year[MAX_VAL_LEN + 1];
} data_info_t;

/* struct of node */
typedef struct node node_t;
struct node{
    data_info_t *info;
    node_t *next;
};

char info_string[MAX_LINE_LEN];
```

/*escape the first line */
fgets(info_string, MAX_LINE_LEN, fp);

```
/* separate the data put them into node and them put the node into the list */
while(fgets(info_string, MAX_LINE_LEN, fp) != NULL) {

    char *ptr = strtok(info_string, ",");
    
    strcpy(one_line->info->census_year, ptr);
}
```

Comment: the length for ptr can't be bigger than MAX_VAL_LE

Comment: The code fragment is incomplete, and you did not provide an exact description of the problem you are facing.